# How to create a "long-running" version of "\classicstylenums" in "kpfonts" package?

Tags: oldstylenums, kpfonts

I'm using `kpfonts` in my document with old style numbers. However, in some sections (e.g. figures and tables), I want to revert to the normal style numbers. There is a command for doing that - `\classicstylenums` - but the text has to be given as an argument, like so: `\classicstylenums{text text text text}` Instead of having to repeat the command for each text segment, I want to declare it once, like so: `\myclassicstylenums text text text ...` And by doing it within a group, the text reverts back to old style numbers.

Anyone has any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can revert to lined numbers by defining

```
\newcommand\linednumbers{%
  \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{jkp}%
  \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{jkpss}%
  \normalfont}
```

This is a declaration that will respect grouping; so, for example, you can put it inside a `table` environment.

You can also use it as an environment by itself:

```
\begin{linednumbers}
Material with lined numbers
\end{linednumbers}
```

but it's best to use it for complete paragraphs.

If one is devious enough to use the `fulloldstylenums` option, then something more is needed:

```
\newcommand\linednumbers{%
  \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{jkp}%
  \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{jkpss}%
  \normalfont\mathversion{lined}}
\DeclareMathVersion{lined}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{lined}{OT1}{jkp}{m}{n}
```

Comment: I've noticed that this doesn't work for math mode. Could you augment your answer to include that as well?

Comment: @gablin See edited message; I wouldn't use `fulloldstylenums` except for reproducing very old books (but I don't think that the Kp fonts are suitable for this).

Comment: Ah damn, didn't realize that `kpfonts` had two separate options for old style numbers. That solved my problem! Thanks!